# How to allow IErrorHandlers to handle AccessViolationExceptions in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, com, windows-services

Sure, we must avoid catching and attempting to handle AccessViolationExceptions(AVEs). However, in my current case, the exception is thrown from a COM+ managed component which terminates the process that threw the exception, therefore, cleaning up correctly. However, a windows service, hosting WCF, that consumes said COM+ component receives the bubbled up AVE causing the service crash.

The IErrorHandlers in place don't seem to fire/detect AVEs.

Is there any way to enable WCF IErrorHandlers to catch AVEs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for IErrorHandlers to catch exceptions similar to AccessViolationExceptions (SEHExceptions).

Answer (score 1):

As a variant you can try to add a handler on   [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) where you can restart a service again.

Or, you can run your main win_service in one ('Main')AppDomain and host the WCF service in another ('Sub')AppDomain. In such way you can unloaded(reload) the sub-proccess without affecting the main process.

Comment: See, my main concern is with other ongoing wcf calls that essentially are abnormally terminated due to an EAV on a different service. With both approaches, I need to forcefully terminate the app domain running my WCF services. This is what I'm trying to avoid.
I'm already restarting the service on first failure.